# Ctrl + Space doesn't show auto complete list on VSCode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, power-toys

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> is a shortcut in Visual Studio Code to show the auto-complete list, but it doesn't show it anymore, I reset the shortcuts to default, but the issue is still the same.

The Visual Studio Code version is **1.78.2** 
OS: **Windows**

Answer (score 2):

As @chronos1970 [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183278#issuecomment-1560771117), the issue is because of the latest [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) version (v0.70.0), which bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to the new Peek widget, which will block the shortcut in any program including VSCode.

To fix this issue, you need to open PowerToys and click on the Peek tab, then change the shortcut to something else instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

[image: Screenshot of PowerToys Peek tab]